# How can I align a video to the right?

Tags: html, css, video, responsive

I have an HTML5 video with a height greater than its width. I gave the video `100% in height` and `100% in width`, so it scales automatically depending ob my window size.

But I want the video to be on the right ob its container. In the image below, you can see that the video places its content in center..

How can I achieve that?

[screenshot of video element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGfwn.png)

```css
.container {
width: 100%;
display: flex;

}

.left,
.right {
height: 100vh;
width: 50%;
border: 1px dotted blue;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

.video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">

  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <video class="video" playsinline loop autoplay muted>
      <source src="" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: pease provide enough code to reproduce the issue you have. The code you provided is insufficient to reproduce any of the described behavior.

Comment: Just updated it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the video to scale automatically you should use another div to nest your video in. As @tacoshy mentioned, the width 100% is the main problem as it prevents us from using margin-left auto. Hence, losing the scalability.

Now you can use `width: fit-content;` to contain the video and set the height to 100% as expected. Then just add `margin-left: auto;` on the new div instead of the video itself, this way it scales.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.left,
.right {
  height: 100vh;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.right>div {
  height: 100%;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">

  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div>
      <video class="video" playsinline loop autoplay muted>
      <source src="https://marceldiedrich.com/so/video-hor.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Safari Solution (even with shrinking viewport height) ~

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.left,
.right {
  height: 100vh;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.video {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.right>div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">

  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div>
      <video class="video" playsinline loop autoplay muted>
      <source src="https://marceldiedrich.com/so/video-hor.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! But now, the video is still in center as soon as the window is too small in height.. Or do I miss something here?

Comment: @m4424 I don't see the video in the center whatsoever. When I resize vertically it scales and horizontally it scales expected. If you think you're seeing the video in the center I'd love a screenshot.

Comment: Sure, I just shared it in another answer :)

Comment: @m4424 what browser are you on?

Comment: I am using Safari

Comment: Just saw it in chrome and your solution works perfectly! There seems to be an issue with safari.. do you know what it is?

Comment: @m4424 see edits for safari solution. This is where I would be cautious about using viewport units to position elements, as when you have a fixed `100vh` and resize vertically the elements will shrink.

Comment: Thank you very much for adding this! I need the video to be 100vh at any time, now it seems like the div-height is related to the height of the video. Instead, the height of the video should be as high as the window..
Your first solution is exactly what I was looking for, it only does not work in safari yet.

Comment: @m4424 see edits for guaranteed solution for chrome and safari. Sorry I got busy with some stuff. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: That's perfect @カメロン, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is, that the video has a `width: 100%;`. As such it spans the entire parent's width even when the width of the video is smaller than the parent. Remove the `.video { width: 100%; }` to fix that. After that, you can align it to the right of the container by using: `margin-left: auto`

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.left,
.right {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.video {
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">

  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <video class="video" playsinline loop autoplay muted>
      <source src="https://marceldiedrich.com/so/video-hor.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need the video to scale automatically when I resize my window in width. Now, the video gets cropped on its right. 
Is there a way to prevent that? I already tried object-fit...

Comment: if you know the exact size of the video, youc an use `aspect-ratio`. `object-fit: contain;` should not crop videos. Depending of what you actually intend to do, the container should not have a fixed width or a fixed height. if you define a fixed width and height then the video will run into issues asson as the aspect-ration does no longer match.

Comment: @tacoshy See my answer, yes the main conflict is the width: 100%; as you said. But it won't matter if we add another containing div.

Comment: Thanks @tacoshy, but it should work with all sizes of a video - so unfortunately I can't work with exact measurements and aspect-ratios..

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your css style, it is the problem about the `video`. It contains lots of space.

You could use `object-fit` and `width` to change and crop the video

```css
.container {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
}

.left,
.right {
height: 100vh;
width: 50%;
border: 1px dotted blue;
align-items: center;
overflow:hidden
}

.video {
    width: 110%;
    height: 110%;
    border: 2px solid red;
    margin-left:calc(-2vw);
    margin-top:calc(-2vh);
    object-fit:cover
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">

  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <video class="video" playsinline loop autoplay muted>
      <source src="https://marceldiedrich.com/so/video-hor.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP wants the video aligned on the right side of the `.right` div. This is virtually the same as the question.

Comment: @カメロン, you are absolutely right, I realized it several minutes ago just edited the soluation

Comment: Thanks @James nevertheless for helping!